# I Can't open again the 2 Window Childs in MDI Parent

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi

I created a MDI Parent Form (Form1), that has 1 Menu with 2 Items.
Each Item opens a Window Child (Form2 and Form3).
I can open Form2 and Form3, if they are already open they just got the focus.
So far, everything's Ok.
The problem is when i close Form2 and Form3, i can't open them again!
Can anyone help me with this?
Many thanks.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace App51
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    Form2 frm2 = Application.OpenForms["Form2"] as Form2;
    Form3 frm3 = Application.OpenForms["Form3"] as Form3;


public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();
}


private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
  IsMdiContainer = true;
  foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
    if (control is MdiClient)
    {
      control.BackColor = Color.DeepSkyBlue;
      break;
    }
}
  

private void abrirForm2ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (frm2 != null)
  {
    frm2.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    frm2.BringToFront();
    frm2.Activate();
  }
  else
  {
    frm2 = new Form2();
    frm2.MdiParent = this;
    frm2.Show();
  }
}


private void abrirForm3ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (frm3 != null)
  {
    frm3.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    frm3.BringToFront();
    frm3.Activate();
  }
  else
  {
    frm3 = new Form3();
    frm3.MdiParent = this;
    frm3.Show();
  }
}
```

}
}

Comment: How are you closing the child forms?  What happens when you debug your menu click events, which branch is it using?

Comment: Don't keep a reference to a dead form object.  Fix: frm2.FormClosed += delegate { frm2 = null; };

Comment: I'm closing the Child Forms in it's X Button. Even when i close the Child Forms, they remain in Memory (i created 2 Watches in VS Debug Mode to check it).

Comment: In what line of code i put your fix, Hans?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code a bit. Now it works :) What do you think of it?

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace App51
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    Form2 frm2;
    Form3 frm3;


public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();
}


private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
  IsMdiContainer = true;

  if (control is MdiClient)
  {
    control.BackColor = Color.DeepSkyBlue;
    break;
  }
}
  

private void abrirForm2ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (frm2 != null)
  {
    if (frm2.Visible == true)
    {
      frm2.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
      frm2.BringToFront();
      frm2.Activate();
    }
    else
    {
      frm2 = new Form2();
      frm2.FormClosed += delegate { frm2 = null; };
      frm2.MdiParent = this;
      frm2.Show();
    }
  }
  else
  {
    frm2 = new Form2();
    frm2.FormClosed += delegate { frm2 = null; };
    frm2.MdiParent = this;
    frm2.Show();
  }
}


private void abrirForm3ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (frm3 != null)
  {
    if (frm3.Visible == true)
    {
      frm3.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
      frm3.BringToFront();
      frm3.Activate();
    }
    else
    {
      frm3 = new Form3();
      frm3.FormClosed += delegate { frm3 = null; };
      frm3.MdiParent = this;
      frm3.Show();
    }
  }
  else
  {
    frm3 = new Form3();
    frm3.FormClosed += delegate { frm3 = null; };
    frm3.MdiParent = this;
    frm3.Show();
  }
}
```

}
}